# How do I properly delete an array of doubles through a pointer after the pointer has been iterated?

Tags: c++, memory, delete-operator

I have created an array of doubles using the following code:

```
double *points = new double[(ii+1)*(jj+1)*(kk+1)*3];
```

I realize that in order to delete the array, all I have to do is:

```
delete[] points;
```

However; the array is created in a function (called create_points) that passes the address of the first element as follows:

```
return &points[0];
```

The code that calls this function then iterates through the address:

```
double *address = create_points(x_dim,y_dim,z_dim);
for(int k=0; k<x_dim+1; ++k)
    for(int j=0; j<y_dim+1; ++j)
        for(int i=0; i<z_dim+1; ++i) {
            v[p_count].x = *address;
            ++address;
            v[p_count].y = *address;
            ++address;
            v[p_count].z = *address;
            ++address;
            ++p_count;
        }
```

Now my question is, how do I properly delete the array of doubles that address is used to access? Can I simply go `delete[] address`, or do I have to do this some other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot say `delete[] address`, doing so is undefined behavior.  You have to delete it through a pointer to the original base address of the array.  So, if you're going to increment the pointer, you need to remember the original pointer (or recompute it):

```
double *base_address = create_points(...);
double *address = base_address;
// do stuff with address, increment it, etc.
delete [] base_address
```

Comment: Or don't return a pointer at all but return some form of smart pointer that will make sure it is deleted?

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the right address. It does not suffice that the address lies within the allocated region.
Why not keep a copy of the pointer before starting the iteration? `&points[0] == points`

Answer (score 1):

It is only defined behavior to delete what you allocated, and that would be the address returned via `create_points`.The best way would be to iterate over a temporary.

```
double *address = create_points(x_dim,y_dim,z_dim);
double *a = address;
for(int k=0; k<x_dim+1; ++k)
    for(int j=0; j<y_dim+1; ++j)
        for(int i=0; i<z_dim+1; ++i) {
            v[p_count].x = *a;
            ++a;
            v[p_count].y = *a;
            ++a;
            v[p_count].z = *a;
            ++a;
            ++p_count;
        }
delete[] address;
```